# Android Contact images to listview works on emulator but not on device

Tags: java, android

I'm using following code to get the contact images:

```
Contact c = new Contact("", "", "", null);
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,pCur.getLong(pCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID)));

InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
                            if (input != null) {
                                Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                                c.setContactImage(photo);
                            }                           
contacts.add(c);
```

I add the contact information to my view in an adapter class with the following code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder = null;
if(convertView == null) {
holder.img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContact);
Contact entry = getItem(position);

if(entry.getContactImage()!=null){
     holder.img.setImageBitmap(entry.getContactImage());
}

}


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView number;
    ImageView img;
}
```

manifest has the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

This seems to work perfectly on emulator, but when I test it on my android device it doesn't work. I added the images to my contacts in the same way, both emulator and device are on 2.3, the device is a HTC sensation XL.

The other information I get from my contact list works perfectly on both. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

How to do it:

```
public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long id) {
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
            InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
            if (input == null) {
                return null;
           }
           return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        }
```

This is how you call on the function:

```
c.setContactImage(loadContactPhoto(cr, pCur.getLong(pCur.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your Manifest for permission to read contacts and MinSDkVersion values.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

If you are using Android 2.3  then Minsdk version should be "9"

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
```

Comment: Also check this links 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211665/load-contact-photo-in-a-listview-performance
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829601/android-load-contact-photos-to-a-list

Comment: Already had the uses permission added, forgot to add it to the post.

Comment: Found out how to do this, adding it to the original post if someone has the same problem :)